# pass formula expressions in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to pass a formula expression into mutate to create a new variable.

```
expression1 <- formula(ifelse(Var1 == 9, 0, Var1))

df <- data.frame(Var1 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 Var2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>%
      mutate(new_var = expression1)
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is a string, then we can parse it

```
library(dplyr)
expression1 <-  'ifelse(Var1 == 9, 0, Var1)'
df %>% 
   mutate(new_var = eval(rlang::parse_expr(expression1)))
```

-output

```
#    Var1 Var2 new_var
#1     7    7       7
#2     5    7       5
#3     5    2       5
#4     4    6       4
#5     7    9       7
#6     9    3       0
#7     9    5       0
#8     2    9       2
#9     9    2       0
#10   10    9      10
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 Var2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: if this answered your question, you can click 'accept answer' to mark this question as answered @user8304241

Answer (score 2):

`rlang` prefers to use expressions or quosures rather than formulas. It would be better to use

```
expression1 <- rlang::expr(ifelse(Var1 == 9, 0, Var1))

df <- data.frame(Var1 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 Var2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(new_var = !!expression1)
```

First you create the expression with the `expr()` function. Then you "inject" that into the dplyr expression you want to call with `!!`